# How to choose max of one column per other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, max

I am using SQL Server and I have a table "a"

```
month  segment_id   price
-----------------------------
  1      1            100       
  1      2            200     
  2      3             50     
  2      4             80      
  3      5             10
```

I want to make a query which presents the original columns where the price will be the max per month

The result should be:

```
month  segment_id   price
----------------------------     
  1      2            200        
  2      4             80      
  3      5             10
```

I tried to write SQL code:

```
Select 
    month, segment_id, max(price) as MaxPrice
from 
    a
```

but I got an error:

> Column **segment_id** is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either **an aggregate function** or **the GROUP BY clause**

I tried to fix it in many ways but didn't find how to fix it

Comment: Why are the table data and the expected results are same ?

Comment: Please do not vandalise your questions; they are valuable to other visitors here that want to solve the same problem. I note that your question was never *changed* with edits, all that editors did was adjust formatting, grammar and spelling.

Answer (score 3):

Because you need a group by clause without segment_id

```
Select month, max(price) as MaxPrice 
  from a
 Group By month
```

as you want results per each month, and segment_id is non-aggregated in your original select statement.

If you want to have segment_id with maximum price repeating per each month for each row, you need to use max() function as window analytic function without Group by clause

```
Select month, segment_id, 
       max(price) over ( partition by month order by segment_id ) as MaxPrice 
  from a
```

**Edit** (due to your lastly edited desired results) **:** you need one more window analytic function `row_number()` as @Gordon already mentioned:

```
Select month, segment_id, price From
(
Select a.*,
       row_number() over ( partition by month order by price desc ) as Rn
  from a
  ) q
Where rn = 1
```

Comment: but I want also to display the segment_id column, so what can I do

Comment: @michaeldonte I edited due to your last desired results.

Comment: thank you, is there an option in SQL to get immediately the short cut in analytical function. in this example, can I get the max price per every month and it's segment_id without seeing all the extra rows we eliminate in next operation in the qurey (where rn =1), to just get it by one query?

Comment: @michaeldonte you're welcome. You can prefer to use John Cappelleti's option to use window analytic function without a subquery, which is stated within the Order By clause.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.price = (select max(t2.price) from t t2 where t2.month = t.month);
```

The "canonical" solution is to use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by month order by price desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

With the right indexes, the correlated subquery often performs better.

Answer (score 1):

Only because it was not mentioned.

Yet another option is the **WITH TIES** clause.

**To be clear**, the approach by Gordon and Barbaros would be a nudge more performant, but this technique does not require or generate an extra column.

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable 
 Order By row_number() over (partition by month order by price desc)
```

Comment: very nice option John.

Answer (score 0):

With `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where month = t.month and price > t.price
)
```

or:

```
select t.*
from tablename inner join (
  select month, max(price) as price 
  from tablename 
  group By month
) g on g.month = t.month and g.price = t.price
```